# sum two columns and subtract from another sum of two columns in sql using VB6

Tags: sql, vb6

I have a single table which i want to use a single SQL statement from Visual basic 6 platform to Select and subtract summed column based on where clause. Below is the Description
Here is a Sample Table to explain better:

```
ID         Deposit  Withdrawal    Date
ACC01      1000       0         10/10/2012
ACC01      2000       0         1/1/2013
ACC02      3000       0         10/10/2012
ACC02      4000       0         1/1/2013
ACC01      0        1000        12/12/2012
ACC02      0        3000        12/12/2012
```

I want to sum values in deposit column where date less than 1/1/2013 as `DepositBefore`
Also sum values in withdrawal column where date less than 1/1/2013 as `WithDrawalBefore`
then subtract `WithdrawalBefore` from `DepositBefore` (i.e. `BalanceBefore = DepositBefore - WithrawalBefore`)

In the same vein, sum values in deposit column where date >= 1/1/2013 as `DepositAfter`
Also sum values in `Withdrawal` column where date >= 1/1/2013 as `WithdrawalAfter`
so that (`BalanceAfter = DepositAfter - WithdrawalAfter`)

Finally compute `BalanceForInterest = BalanceBefore + BalanceAfter`. Would prefer if a single query can resolve this Thanks in Advance

Below is the code i tried but did not succeed.

```
With rsSaving
.Open "SELECT SUM(SUM(Deposit)-SUM(Withdrawal)) AS BalanceBefore FROM tblSaving WHERE  ID = 'ACC01' AND Date < #1/1/2013# GROUP BY ID, (SELECT SUM(SUM(Deposit)-SUM(Withdrawal)) AS BalanceAfter FROM tblSaving WHERE ID='ACC01' AND Date >= #1/1/2013# GROUP BY ID)",conDB, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic 
.close
End With
set rsSaving = Nothing
```

rsSaving is an ADO object, while conDB is my connection. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. It would be very useful if you posted at least an attempt to do this yourself, or at least an attempt to write the separate queries. Please [edit] to add that if you would be so kind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the SQL query. You may have to change the syntax for your databse (SQL, Access, etc.). You don't need a `GroupBy` because you are getting back a single value. Given your sample data this query returns 2000.

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT SUM(Deposit-Withdrawal) AS Total FROM tblSaving WHERE ID = 'ACC01' AND Date < '1-1-2013')
      + (SELECT SUM(Deposit-Withdrawal) AS Total FROM tblSaving WHERE  ID = 'ACC01' AND Date >= '1-1-2013')
        AS BalanaceAfter
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jac for quick response, i clearly understood your query and believed it should work, but VB6 returned error 2147467259 (unspecified error) after making necessary changes particularly for date (i.e '1-1-2013' to #1/1/2013#). Please what would you advice.

Comment: @ProDev What is the database? Have you tried iterating the connection error collection for a more descriptive error?

Answer (score 0):

you can write like

```
declare @BalanceBefore  int
set @BalanceBefore = (select sum(deposit ) from table where date < 1/1/2013)


declare @WithdrawalAfter int
set @WithdrawalAfter = (select sum(WithdrawalAfter ) from table where date > 1/1/2013)

declare @res int
set @res = @BalanceBefore   - @WithdrawalAfter 

print @res
```

try some thing like this. also check for date comparison